# Is it possible to define a layer which will retry to load, e.g. with exponential back-off?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, leaflet

I am using OpenLayers to connect to a home-grown server, and unlike professional grade servers like Google or Cloudmade that box will actually take a while to calculate the result for a specific tile. And as it is a mathematical function I am plotting, there is no big chance to accelerate the server or even pre-render the tiles.

My initial trials with Leaflet quickly came to the conclusion that Leaflet actually leaves all of the reloading and load-error handling to the browser, while OpenLayers at least has an event that is fired when the tile server does return with an error code.

The idea I am following was to basically start rendering a tile when it was requested and fire an HTTP 503 immediately, relying on the client to try again.

To try again, I implemented a simple layer like this:

```
    var myLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.MYLayer("mine", {
        'transparent':"true",
        'format':"image/png",
        'isBaseLayer':false});
    myLayer.events.register("tileerror", myLayer, function (param) {
        // Try again:
        var targetURL = param.tile.layer.getURL(param.tile.bounds);
        var tile = param.tile;
        tile.timeout = tile.hasOwnProperty("timeout") ? tile.timeout * 2 : 1000;
        setTimeout(function (tileToLoad, url) {
            if (tileToLoad.url === url) {
                tileToLoad.clear();
                tileToLoad.url = url;
                tileToLoad.initImage();
            }
        }.bind(undefined, tile, targetURL), tile.timeout);
    });
```

I figured out the code required to reload a tile from the source of OpenLayers, but maybe there is a cleaner way to accomplish this.

My problem is: The tiles themselves are reused, as are the divs in the DOM, so the reload procedure might actually try to reload a tile into a DIV that long as been successfully reused, e.g. because the user scrolled to someplace else where the server was able to provide data quickly.

The question I guess boils down to - is there an official way to use the tileerror event to simply try to reloading, or at least a simpler way in the API to trigger a reload? I spent quite a while in the source of OpenLayers itself but couldn't shed light on why it is still going wrong (the test for tileToLoad.url == url didn't really do it).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some more trial and error I found that I could actually add an eventListener to my Layer class, which will do what I want - try to reload the tile again after a certain wait. The trick was the consecutive call of setImgSrc() for cleanup and to draw with the true parameter, which effectively is an (undocumented) force flag. Thanks to the code!

```
OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.MyLayer= OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Layer.OSM, {
initialize:function (name, options) {
    var url = [
       "xxxx"
    ];
    options = OpenLayers.Util.extend({
        "tileOptions":{
            eventListeners:{
                'loaderror':function (evt) {
                    // Later reload
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        console.log("Drawing ", this);
                        this.setImgSrc();
                        this.draw(true);
                    }.bind(this), 3000); // e.g. after 3 seconds
                }
            }
        }
    }, options);
    var newArguments = [name, url, options];
    OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.prototype.initialize.apply(this, newArguments);
},

CLASS_NAME:"OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.MyLayer"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the following resources:

- http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Util-js.html#Util.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS
- http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Tile-js.html
- http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Tile/Image-js.html

Comment: Hi Christophe, thanks - I had seen and tried the Image Reload Attempt variable, and this does work, but it tries to reload immediately. Effectively, what I would like to do is to wait a while before retrying. I know how to get an event that the load failed, but I cannot figure how to actually reload correctly. I can't get it to work by just mimicking what the source code does on reload (which is Image setImgSrc()), so I would assume I need to call different methods (which is my attempt above with clear() and initImage(), but that screws up the reused tiles as explained in my question).

Comment: Oh, thanks, I had not thought about the subdivision of stackexchange! I will try my luck over there!